# List of lists as Input to a Keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement a model for which the input should be a list of lists:

```
inputs = [ [np.array([...]), ..., np.array([...])], [np.array([...]), ..., np.array([...])] ]
```

I can not convert the inner lists in two np array since the shapes of them don't allow that.

When I pass the inputs to the model I receive the following error:

```
Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays.
```

How can I feed my inputs to the model?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must have compatible shapes, that's unavoidable.

The only case that accepts list of lists if when you have model with "more than one input tensor".

The solutions for you are:

- Padding the data: add a padding so every array has the same shape
- Train separate arrays, one at a time, using `train_on_batch` instead of fit in a manual training loop. Each of the separate arrays must have a well defined shape.